# Why my query not correct work?

Tags: sql-server

I'm new in `sql server`,write this query:

```
SELECT top 20 y.Telno,
        t.Cycle+'-'+y.Cycle Cycle,
        ((y.CurBill - t.CurBill)/y.CurBill) Price
FROM [ClubEatc].[dbo].[GetOnlineBills] y
INNER JOIN [ClubEatc].[dbo].[GetOnlineBills] t
    ON y.Telno = t.TelNo AND CAST(y.Cycle as int)-1 = CAST(t.Cycle as int)
```

in real data have a this record on `GetOnlineBills` in `Cycle=952`:

```
TelNo         CurBill   TotalBill   ExecuteDate     Cycle
4133223011      43       1209337     1395/4/21      952
```

And in `Cycle=951`:

```
TelNo       CurBill  TotalBill  ExecuteDate Cycle
4133223011   349      1209295   1395/4/21    951
```

in calculate `calc` this formula:

```
(Curbill.Cycle[952]-Curbill.Cycle[951])/Curbill.Cycle[952]=((349-43))/349=0.87
```

but up query show me this:

```
-7.11627906976744
```

what happen?Where i mistake?thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ur code is doing ((43-349))/43 and giving result –

use below code...

```
 SELECT top 20 y.Telno,
         t.Cycle+'-'+y.Cycle Cycle,
        ((t.CurBill - y.CurBill)/t.CurBill) Price FROM [ClubEatc].[dbo].[GetOnlineBills] y INNER JOIN
 [ClubEatc].[dbo].[GetOnlineBills] t
     ON y.Telno = t.TelNo AND CAST(y.Cycle as int)-1 = CAST(t.Cycle as int)
```